# dynamic code evaluation code injection in window.setTimout

Tags: javascript, settimeout, fortify

I have the following code executed to handle the popup blocked situation in browser. But we are facing a fortify critical issue in the setTimeout function.Can somebody help me to resolve this

```js
var myWindow = window.open("", '_blank');
if (myWindow != undefined) {
  window.setTimeout(function() {
    myWindow.document.write(text);
    myWindow.focus();
    myWindow.document.title = name;
  }, 100);
} else {
  showWarning({
      message: 'popup is blocked')
  });
} // here
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue isn't with the set timeout.

When you are doing the window.open, it's being blocked by a blocker but if you look at the return data, myWindow will be an empty object.  This therefore means you'll hit the else part of the if else.

Change the code to be:

```
var myWindow = window.open("", '_blank');
if (Object.keys(myWindow).length !== 0) {
    window.setTimeout(function () {
        myWindow.document.write(text);
        myWindow.focus();
        myWindow.document.title = name;
    }, 100);
} else {
    showWarning({message: 'popup is blocked')});           
}
```